# Connect Adafruit Ultimate GPS Logger Shield and Raspberry Pi 2 B

Tags: raspbian, python, gps

I'm trying to connect Adafruit Ultimate GPS Logger Shield with Raspberry Pi 2 B, and it still not working.

I tried to connect: Gnd, Rx, Tx, 5v. And it have signal at FIX leds. I also setup some command-line: sudo apt-get install gpsd gpsd-clients python-gps
and test it with 'cgps -s'

I also try to do something in this site: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-hat-for-raspberry-pi/pi-setup

and when I run this step 'cat /dev/ttyAMA0'. It didn't show anything.

Please help me what can I do next. 
Thanks.